# Behavior of R formulas with respect to the bound environment

Tags: r

I'm wondering about some of the details in how R binds environments to formulas, and what is required of said environments in different situations, specifically with regards to whether ~ is on is not included in the formula.

Let's say I have two formula like strings, which in general will have been created programmatically, but for simplicity I will just define as literals:

```
$ formula_str_no_tilde <- "a + b"
$ formula_str_with_tilde <- "~ a + b"
```

I intend to use these to create a model matrix further on down the line, from a data frame that includes a and b columns.  To that end, I want to convert the formula-like-strings to legit formulas.  Here is where there is quite curious differing behavior:

```
$ formula_no_tilde <- as.formula(formula_str_no_tilde)
> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a' not found
```

while:

```
$ formula_with_tilde <- as.formula(formula_str_with_tilde)
no error
```

Checking the documentation for as.formula, there is an env argument that is used to bind an environment to the formula.  This argument binds the global environment by default, which makes some sense of the error message because we haven't got an 'a' in our global environment.  It does make the acceptance of the second call to as.formula mysterious though, as we are in the same situation...

Since the global environment is bound, one would be sane to suspect that maybe this whole adventure is misguided, and we will not be able to use our formula_with_tilde to make a model matrix later on down the road because the global environment is already bound.  Nonetheless:

```
$ D <- data.frame('a'=c(1, 2, 3), 'b'=c(-1, 0, 1))
$ model.matrix(formula_with_tilde, D)
```

works as you would naively hope.  Possibly this is a feature of model.matrix, it rebinds the environment for you...

So here are my questions:

- Are formulas without tildes illegal in R?  Is there any situation in which then make sense?
- Why does not including the tilde throw an environment lookup error, while including it does not?
- Does model.matrix rebind the environment associated with a formula?

and for completeness:

- Are there better pro starts for producing and manipulating formulas programmatically?

Comment: You may wish to read the details section of `help(formula)`.  It's quite informative

Comment: The tilde is a prefix or infix function that returns a call object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an *unevaluated* call-object (which is the sort of R language object that the tilde operator returns) then you can use `call`:

```
 call( '+',quote(a),quote(b))
 #a + b
```

You would need to prevent the default operation of the interpreter to evaluate the second and third arguments by surrounding with `quote`. You could use the result as a legitimate first argument to `eval and use a dataframe as the environment:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=1:10)
eval( call( '+',quote(a),quote(b)), dat)
# [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

The answer to the question "is the tilde part of the formula": is probably, yes, if we are to believe this:

```
 (~a)[[1]]
#`~`
```

And to build a functional result from the string "a+b" this would be one way:

```
 as.call( parse(text="a+b") )
#(a + b)()
```

"Does model.matrix rebind the environment associated with a formula?"

Well, not exactly, at least as I understand the question. `model.matrix` pulls in values from the model.frame, which is an augmented dataframe, but it does not have an attached environment in its attributes list.

It's interesting to look at what some these language objects have as attributes:

```
> class(bquote(a+b))
[1] "call"
> identical( bquote(a+b), ~a+b)
[1] FALSE

> attributes( ~a+b)
$class
[1] "formula"

$.Environment
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>

> attributes( bquote(a+b))
NULL
```

With a=1 and b=2 in the Globalenv and dat as above:

```
> eval(  (~a+b)[[2]], envir=dat)
 [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
> 
> eval( (~a+b)[[2]] )
[1] 3
```

Addendum: Konrad's comment, which points out that the arguments to eval can be any one of formula call or expression so you don't need the `as.call`'s, prompts me furhter illustrate  that `eval` and `evalq` can be used to produce outcomes that mirror the differences above with just the expression a+b:

```
> evalq( a+b, envir=dat)
 [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
> eval( a+b, envir=dat)   # evaluated in current scope despite  envir=dat
[1] 3
```

Comment: And `quote(a + b)` will also return the same call

Comment: I was hoping that people would learn that tilde was a function that returned a call object, so was trying to stay as "functional" in notation as I could. I started with `call('+', a,b)` and gotten `~("+", 1, 2)` where 'a' and 'b' were 1 and 2 in the global env.

Comment: There’s actually a difference between what `~` returns (a `formula` object) and what `call('+' …)` returns (a `language` object). In particular, a `formula` has an environment attached.

Comment: `as.call` is also completely redundant here: `is.call((~a+b)[[2]])` → `TRUE`.

Comment: @BondedDust:  This is exactly the kind of detailed answer I was hoping for, thank you!  I'm going to take some time to absorb it, and I may have some follow up questions.  Just wanted to let you know asap that I appreciate the level of detail you provided.

Comment: @BondedDust In response to your edit: I didn’t mean that both can be used equivalently. I mean that they are **the same**. `is.call` in your example is a no-op, it’s taking a call and returning the same call (and not even a copy of the call, but in fact a reference to the same object location in memory, as can be checked via `pryr::address`). `~a + b` is a `formula`. However, `(~a + b)[[2]]` is *not* a `formula`, it’s the `call` which is stored inside a `formula` alongside with the formula’s execution environment.

Comment: I haven't disputed your comment. And I didn't think that `(~a + b)[[2]]` returned a formula. I'll remove the redundancy.